# Facebook Login Yielding URL: Blocked (not whitelisted)

Tags: angular, facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-javascript-sdk

I signed up for Facebook Social login and I am using v2.10 of the API.

I can get the login window to open up just fine, but I get the following error.

> URL blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not
>   white-listed in the app's client OAuth settings. Make sure that the
>   client and web OAuth logins are on and add all your app domains as
>   valid OAuth redirect URIs.

I have tried everything to get it working, but can't seem to crack the issue.

** Environment

- Windows 10
- Angular 5
- Node 8.10
- Pingable at https://localhost:5000 and https://scormify.app

**What I have tried:**

- Adding all possible variations of the redirect uri.   Including the uri listed in the window.   (`&redirect_uri=https://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/r/FdM1l_dpErI.js?version=42#cb=f2332406d58ffb`)
- Per [This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38701227/3946099), added a hostfile configuration to redirect to a non-localhost
- Tried to track down any debugging information.  Tried the network inspector to see if it was reaching out anywhere, etc.
- Read through the snark in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509771/url-blocked-this-redirect-failed-because-the-redirect-uri-is-not-whitelisted)
- [Consulted this article](https://codeburst.io/node-js-rest-api-facebook-login-121114ee04d8)

  - Double checked domains under the top-level app settings.

Image showing all variations of the callback url, including the faux domain entered into the host file and the redirect uri from the window (staticxx....) and the actual localhost callback url.
[image: Fb App Settings]

**host file**
`127.65.43.21     scormify.app` (also did netsh [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36646749/3946099))

**FB SDK Init** FYI only, dont think this has anything to do with it.

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
      appId: 'xxx',
      cookie: true,
      xfbml: true,
      version: 'v2.10'
    });

```
FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
```

};
```

**Angular 5 Svc Code** I don't think this is the problem either, FYI only.

```
  linkFb() {
    return FB.login(result => {
      if (result.authResponse) {
        return this.http.post(`https://localhost:5000/api/v1/account/link/fb/callback`, { access_token: result.authResponse.accessToken }).map((res: ApiResponse) => res)
      }
    }, { scope: 'public_profile,email' });
  }
```

**Routes**

```
  .post(
    '/account/link/fb',
    passport.authenticate('facebook-token', { session: false }),
    account.linkFb
  )
  .get('/account/link/fb/callback', account.linkFbCb)
```

**Passport Strategy**

```
  passport.use(
    new FacebookStrategy(
      {
        clientID: config.FACEBOOK_APPID,
        clientSecret: config.FACEBOOK_SECRET,
        callbackURL: `https://localhost:5000/api/v1/account/link/fb/callback`,
        profileFields: ['name', 'email', 'link'],
        passReqToCallback: true
      },
      (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        console.log(req);
        console.log(profile);
        // make profile;
        // make provider
        //store.upsertUser();
      }
    )
  );
};
```

Comment: what is the url, on which your application is running ?

Comment: Edit: Added my environment

Comment: If your local url is https://localhost:5000, then you should add "https://localhost:5000" in the redirect uri's. Also enable the "Client OAuth Login" option available on the top.

Comment: Localhost:5000 is the 2nd entry.  I have flipped all the settings on and off.

Comment: Did you enabled the "Client OAuth Login" option ?

Comment: Also one thing. What have you mentioned in the Site URL ? You will find that under the Setting(Basic) section.